# Intercepting link clicks using .NET

Tags: .net

I want to write a program that will intercept all click-at-link events from all over the system (most likely on the websites and inside e-mails) and instead of doing what would normally be done (opening a new tab in the current browser, or launching the default browser), it does something else (displays a pop-up for the sake of the example). Is this possible?

Comment: Why not just register your custom application as default browser?

Comment: @Bobby that won't help intercept clicks in other applications.

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: May I ask as to the purpose? Why do you wish to do what you want to do? It seems intended for malware, and I have no intention of helping foster that. However, if there's some goal you wish to achieve that can be done in another way, I'd be happy to help with that.

Comment: Bobby's solution will intercept clicks in other applications. In fact it is the only solution unless you plan to write plugins for all browsers anyone could ever possibly use. Of course what you are doing seems like an idea doomed from the start.

Comment: @Bobby: Because I want to bind different links to different browsers.

Comment: @David Lively: It will intercept all clicks if the applications honors the default browser. Otherwise there will be a hardcoded call to the browser which you can't intercept anyway. Okay, you could do the parse and deciding what browser in that custom application.

Comment: And I'm doing this because a friend asked me if it's possible to open all microsoft.com links in IE and I want to write an app that does that.

Comment: @Hui: Wouldn't it be better to get [IE Tab](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/ie-tab/) for that? I mean, it's the sole purpose of that plugin (also available for Chrome).

Answer (score 0):

it is not possible as you describe, click microsoft.com links opens IE all others open in default/other browser.

Best option is @Bobby's to create a custom default browser that will be used when a application honours the system setting for default browser and there are plenty that do not.
In the custom app fork either IE or the alternate based on the address passed in.